# Query Excluding Values Found in Two Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I couldn't find this in the forum or much less know how to describe it.

The Setup:
I have a database where I've joined quite a few tables containing people, their assignments, and time entry.  This is a flattened view so the time entry has attributes associated with it and the project also has its own attributes.  The time entry and project both have a customer associated with them

The problem:
I need to perform a couple discrepancy queries.  The person should not be charging to a project they are not assigned.  I only want to see those.  The challenge I am running into is if the person can be assigned to multiple customers.  The way the tables are joined this can be misleading after joined with the time entry data.  IE:

```
Person | Assigned Customer | Time Entry Customer
Joe    | Customer A        | Customer C
Joe    | Customer B        | Customer C
Joe    | Customer B        | Customer A
```

In the example output above Row's 1 and 3 should be filtered out since 'Joe' is assigned to Customer A (row 1) and is charging to Customer A (row 3).

I have tried to do an EXISTS statement to filter things out but I just cant wrap my head around the syntax (I know the results are the same as if I don't have the EXISTS clause in the query below):

```
SELECT A.[Assigned Engineer]
    ,YEAR(A.[Date]) AS [Year]
    ,dbo.ISOweek(A.[Date]) AS [Week]
    ,A.[Customer] AS [Charging Customer]
    ,A.[Project Customer] AS [Project Customer]
    ,SUM(A.[Hours]) AS [Hours]
FROM SkyNet.dbo.PROJECT_ASSIGNMENT_AND_CHARGES_DASHBOARD A
WHERE A.[Customer] NOT LIKE '%' + A.[Project Customer] +'%'
    AND YEAR(A.[Date])=2015
    AND dbo.ISOweek(A.[Date])=1
    AND EXISTS
    (SELECT B.[Assigned Engineer]
    ,YEAR(B.[Date]) AS [Year]
    ,dbo.ISOweek(A.[Date]) AS [Week]
    ,B.[Customer] AS [Charging Customer]
    ,B.[Project Customer] AS [Project Customer]
    ,SUM(B.[Hours]) AS [Hours]
    FROM SkyNet.dbo.PROJECT_ASSIGNMENT_AND_CHARGES_DASHBOARD B
    WHERE A.[Assigned Engineer]=B.[Assigned Engineer]
        AND A.[Customer] NOT LIKE '%' + B.[Project Customer] +'%'
    GROUP BY B.[Assigned Engineer], YEAR(B.[Date]), dbo.ISOweek(B.[Date]),     B.[Customer], B.[Project Customer]
    )
GROUP BY A.[Assigned Engineer], YEAR(A.[Date]), dbo.ISOweek(A.[Date]), A.    [Customer], A.[Project Customer]
ORDER BY A.[Assigned Engineer]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

EDIT - 2/27/2015

Here is some sample data as requested:

```
 Assigned Engineer | Date     | Charging Customer | Project Customer | Hours
 Joe               | 1/4/2015 | Customer A - EAST | Customer A       | 8
 Joe               | 1/4/2015 | Customer B        | Customer A       | 16
 Joe               | 1/4/2015 | Customer A - EAST | Customer C       | 8
 Joe               | 1/4/2015 | Customer B        | Customer C       | 16
```

Comment: `EXISTS` only checks that *something* comes back from the sub-query; it doesn't care what. So, selecting several columns is a waste. The same is (mostly) true of the `GROUP BY` which can combine rows, but will never leave out rows (unless using `HAVING` but that's not the case here). So, that part of the query could have been `AND EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM  SkyNet.dbo.PROJECT_ASSIGNMENT_AND_CHARGES_DASHBOARD B
    WHERE A.[Assigned Engineer]=B.[Assigned Engineer]
        AND A.[Customer] NOT LIKE '%' + B.[Project Customer] +'%'
    )`.

Comment: Why are you using `A.[Customer] NOT LIKE '%' + A.[Project Customer] +'%'` instead of `A.[Customer] <> A.[Project Customer]` ?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your example. As I see it, Joe is never recording his time to the assigned customer ([Assigned Customer]<>[Time Entry Customer]). Why is row 2 (B,C) ok, but the other two (A,C) & (B,A) not ok? Can you please clarify perhaps with relevant table structure(s) and sample data?

Comment: Thank you for commenting.  Ill provide some sample data for "Joe" out of the main table.  The reason I am using NOT LIKE is because the data comes from two different sources, one uses a truncated version of the customer name while the other might use the entire name (sometimes with additional info like "-EAST")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have answered my own question... My forehead just needed to reach the drywall in the wall :)  I knew it would be something simple, but I couldn't get there fast enough.  Using a COUNT and subquery I was able to filter out all the records where the charging customer was like the assigned customer.  I hope this is able to help others in the future:

```
SELECT A.[Assigned Engineer]
    ,YEAR(A.[Date]) AS [Year]
    ,dbo.ISOweek(A.[Date]) AS [Week]
    ,A.[Customer] AS [Charging Customer]
    ,A.[Project Customer] AS [Project Customer]
    ,A.[Hours]
FROM SkyNet.dbo.PROJECT_ASSIGNMENT_AND_CHARGES_DASHBOARD A
WHERE A.[Customer] NOT LIKE '%' + A.[Project Customer] + '%'
    AND 1>(SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM SkyNet.dbo.PROJECT_ASSIGNMENT_AND_CHARGES_DASHBOARD B
        WHERE A.[Assigned Engineer]=B.[Assigned Engineer]
            AND YEAR(A.[Date])=YEAR(B.[Date])
            AND dbo.ISOweek(A.[Date])=dbo.ISOweek(B.[Date])
            AND A.[Customer] LIKE '%' + B.[Project Customer] + '%'
            AND A.[Hours]=B.[Hours])
ORDER BY A.[Assigned Engineer]
    ,YEAR(A.[Date])
    ,dbo.ISOweek(A.[Date])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can this be solved by doing a left join? In my join, I'm looking at rows that match an assigned customer against a row with that same customer as the project customer. Then, in my where clause, I only pull back rows where that match wasn't found.

```
SELECT A.[Assigned Engineer]
    ,YEAR(A.[Date]) AS [Year]
    ,dbo.ISOweek(A.[Date]) AS [Week]
    ,A.[Customer] AS [Charging Customer]
    ,A.[Project Customer] AS [Project Customer]
    ,SUM(A.[Hours]) AS [Hours]
FROM SkyNet.dbo.PROJECT_ASSIGNMENT_AND_CHARGES_DASHBOARD A
left outer join SkyNet.dbo.PROJECT_ASSIGNMENT_AND_CHARGES_DASHBOARD B
    ON A.[Assigned Engineer] = B.[Assigned Engineer] AND
       (B.[Customer] LIKE A.[Project Customer] + '%' = OR A.[Customer] LIKE B.[Project Customer] + '%')
WHERE b.[Customer] IS NULL
```

EDIT: Changed join to reflect OP's data.

Comment: Looks promising... I am testing it now.  Had to modify with a GROUP BY statement since we have an aggregate SUM function

Comment: No this didnt work :(  I added '%' to each end since the project customer and charging customer are not an exact match, but no joy.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: If your data always has the Project Customer with the truncated set, see the change I made to the query above--only one side should have the %'s. However, you really should look into using numeric keys to represent the users to make this easier on yourself in the future.